# how to avoid duplicate entries in akita store?

Tags: angular-akita

Before sending API request to insert I want to check the item is already exist in store or not, if not then only send the request to insert.

```
add(){
   const item = {id: 4,name:'test1',description:'description'}

   // here i want to check whether test1 already exist or not

   this.store.add(item);
   this.httpService.insert(item).subscribe(
   result => {
    this.messageService.handleSuccess('inserted');
    this.store.updateId(id, result.id);
  },
  error => this.messageService.handleError('error on insert:', error)
);
```

can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query:

```
add(){
   const item = {id: 4,name:'test1',description:'description'}

   if(query.hasEntity(4)) {
     // exists
   }

   this.store.add(item);
   this.httpService.insert(item).subscribe(
   result => {
    this.messageService.handleSuccess('inserted');
    this.store.updateId(id, result.id);
  },
  error => this.messageService.handleError('error on insert:', error)
);
```